# Entries sorted by title have some entries not alphabetical

Tags: templating

I have the following code to return some grants, but whilst most of the entries are coming back alphabetically ordered, after the last "Z" entry, there are a few more entries also alphabetically ordered. But they are all the same category.

```
{% set searchParams = {
    relatedTo:  relationParam,
    section: 'grants',
    limit: 9,
    order: 'categoryYearForSorting desc, title asc'
} %}

{% paginate craft.entries(searchParams) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

I feel like i've seen this before, but cannot think what the reason might have been :(

Comment: Can you post an example of the returned values?